# UICollectionViewCell gets selected when i scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

[screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZEZ9.png)

I want only 1 option to be selected at a time. It's working fine when I scroll slowly. but when I scroll fast more than 2 options gets selected automatically.
where I am wrong here.
four hours I'm trying to figure it I don't know please anybody shows me where I am wrong

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.menuProperties.menuTitles.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HMenuCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! HMenuCell

    
    let isSelected = indexPath == self.selectedItemIndex ? true : false
    cell.create(indexPath:indexPath,isSelected:isSelected,menuProperties:self.menuProperties)
    
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let menuCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: self.selectedItemIndex) as? HMenuCell {
        menuCell.removeSelection()
    }
    self.selectedItemIndex = indexPath
    if let menuCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? HMenuCell {
            menuCell.createSelection()
        self.menuControllerDelegate?.didSelectMenuItem(selectedIndex: indexPath)
    }
   
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let menuCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: self.selectedItemIndex) as? HMenuCell {
        menuCell.removeSelection()
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if indexPath == self.selectedItemIndex {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

this is my UICollectionViewCell Class

```
class HMenuCell:UICollectionViewCell {
static let identifier = "HMenuCell"
private var menuProperties:HMenuProperties!
private var titleLabel = UILabel()
private var bottomLayer = CALayer()

private func createLabel(title:String){
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: menuProperties.textFontSize)
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = self.menuProperties.cellBackgroundColor
    titleLabel.textColor = self.menuProperties.deselectedTextColor
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addSubview(titleLabel)
    titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
}
func createSelection(){
    let myWidth = titleLabel.frame.width-2
    let bottomLayer = CALayer()
        bottomLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: titleLabel.frame.height+20, width: myWidth, height: 5)
        bottomLayer.backgroundColor = self.menuProperties.underlinerColor.cgColor
    bottomLayer.cornerRadius = 2.5
    titleLabel.layer.addSublayer(bottomLayer)
    titleLabel.textColor = self.menuProperties.selectedTextColor
    self.bottomLayer = bottomLayer
}
func removeSelection(){
    titleLabel.textColor = self.menuProperties.deselectedTextColor
    self.bottomLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    self.bottomLayer = CALayer()
}
func create(indexPath:IndexPath,isSelected:Bool,menuProperties:HMenuProperties){
    self.menuProperties = menuProperties
    createLabel(title: menuProperties.menuTitles[indexPath.row])
    if isSelected{createSelection()}
    else {removeSelection()}
}
```

}

Comment: you have the most common mistake. just write else condition in cellForItemAt and this will be working fine with you

Answer (score 0):

As we know In collection, tableviews we are using `dequeReusable` cells, They are self explanatory of their behaviour.
Remove selection related code from `cellForItemAt` and manage the selection state within the model and reload cells after selection.